# position_dodge not working with geom_label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having problems in adjusting my `geom_label()` in `ggplot2` such that `position_dodge()` is not working. The two labels are on top of each other... any ideas?

reprex:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(
  x = "Position 1",
  y = 0,
  label = c("Label A", "Label B")
) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_label(aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
             position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Apart from the solution given by @seyphaton, a more general way that avoids this issues would be to use the geoms from the [ggrepel](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/) package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `position_dodge2` instead of `position_dodge`

Also documented in the helptext:

> Dodging preserves the vertical position of an geom while adjusting the horizontal position. position_dodge2 is a special case of position_dodge for arranging box plots, which can have variable widths. position_dodge2 also works with bars and rectangles.